# How to strip <a> tags in an xml file?

Tags: php, html, regex, xml, preg-replace

I have a `<a>` tags in an xml file. I want to strip only `<a>` tags.

**For example:**

```
<test>This is a line with <a name="idp173968"></a> tags in it</test>
```

I can't do `str_replace`to replace  tags since `<a>` tag attribute is varied.

**I tried:**

```
preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>/i", "", $content);
```

if the tags is structured like this `<a name="idp173968"/>`, it works fine.

So,How to strip  tags in my case?

**Expected output:**

```
<test>This is a line with tags in it</test>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a very simple regex like

```
<a\s.*?<\/a>
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jD1pY2/4)

**Example**

```
echo preg_replace("/<a\s.*?<\/a>/i", "", $content);
=> <test>This is a line with  tags in it</test>

$content="<test>This is a line with <a name=\"idp173968\"></a> tags in it</test><article-meta>asdf</article-meta>";
echo preg_replace("/<a\s.*?<\/a>/i", "", $content);
=><test>This is a line with  tags in it</test><article-meta>asdf</article-meta>
```

Comment: I have `<article-meta>` tag in my xml file. since this tag has `<a` and `a>` at the start and the end it replaces this too. How to avoid it?

Comment: @VidhyaRaju Just add `\s` in the regex to ensure space after the `<a` . Check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = '<test>This is a line with <a name="idp173968"></a> tags in it</test>';
$pattern = '/<a\s.*?<\/a>/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
?>
```